# Use Progress bar for upload attachment

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I have a xml file as an attachment. I searched on the internet all of them were for uploading by ftp I couldn't figure out how to use them for sending mail so how can I use progress bar to show while it is uploading to the mail?

here is my code for sending email

```
        Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim mailAttachment As Attachment = New Attachment("XMLFile")
        smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("a@ymail.com", "12345")
        smtpServer.Port = 465
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        smtpServer.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"

        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress("a@ymail.com")
        mail.To.Add("a@ymail.com")
        mail.Subject = "110BackUp"
        mail.IsBodyHtml = False
        mail.Body = "XML FILE"
        mail.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment)
        smtpServer.Send(mail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is only have the progress bar while sending the email maybe you can find useful this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962848/progress-bar-in-vb-net)